# Python - parameter of an object and its value as argument of a function

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, keyword

I want to create a generic function that takes as argument different kind of objects which have different types of parameters, like this :

```
def func(obj, param, param_values):
    for param_value in param_values:
        obj.setParam(param=param_value)
        # do some stuff
    end
```

Now I would like to call that function with different objects, which take different parameters names, as such:

```
func(obj1(), width, {1,2,3,4})
func(obj2(), height, {4,5,6})
```

However, when I write it this way, I have an error  saying that 'param' is not a parameter of obj1 and obj2.

How can I write my function such that it's the value of 'param' that is read and not the word 'param'?
Same goes for 'param_value' as I'm anticipating that it could lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setattr` to add attributes to objects.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "hi"

foo = Foo()
foo.a # "hi"

def func(obj, param, param_values):
    setattr(obj, param, param_values)

func(foo, "b", [1,2,3])

foo.b # [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `setattr` function.

E.g:

```
def func(obj, param, param_values):
    for param_value in param_values:
        setattr(obj, param, param_value)
        # do some stuff
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable number of arguments to an object with `**kwargs` and `setattr`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def func(obj, **kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(obj,k,v)

foo = Foo()

func(foo, width={1,2,3,4}, height={4,5,6})

print("width: {}".format(foo.width))
print("height: {}".format(foo.height))
```